# Extracting EXIF data displaying 'Array'

Tags: php, geolocation, exif

Trying to extract the location data from a photo exif, but it's only showing 'Array' for the GPS data. It needs to save the data to a log file on a server for scraping. Am I doing something wrong? The photo definitely has geolocation data on it.

```
<?php
    $image = "narnia.jpg";
    $exif = exif_read_data($image, 0, true);
    foreach ($exif as $key => $section) {
    foreach ($section as $name => $val) {
    echo "$key.$name: $val<pre>\n</pre>";
    }
    }
?>

GPS.GPSLatitudeRef: N
GPS.GPSLatitude: Array
GPS.GPSLongitudeRef: W
GPS.GPSLongitude: Array
GPS.GPSTimeStamp: Array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is, because it is an array.

```
print_r($val);
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/PPJtsB

Comment: Thanks, I added that under the code and it worked. I've tried tweaking it though, to only print the GPS arrays, as that's all I need. 


`$image = "narnia.jpg";
$exif = exif_read_data($image, 0, true);

$lon = getGps($exif["GPSLongitude"], $exif['GPSLongitudeRef']);
$lat = getGps($exif["GPSLatitude"], $exif['GPSLatitudeRef']);

var_dump($lat, lon);`


but that doesn't work. I've also tried `print_r($lat, lon);` instead of `var_dump`